# What is reason controller not able to return the view page

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

> I am using thymeleaf as front end and springboot for back end. But
> when I return my register.html page in register controller, And run
> the application . When hit localhost:8080 in my chrome browser it
> shows error404, page not found.I define my design pages in side the
> templets folder
> Here is the project strcture
> [image]

> StudentController.kt

```
 @GetMapping("/")
    fun home(student: Student, model: Model):String{
        model.addAttribute("courses",courses)
        return "register"
    }

    /**Registration API for Student Registration*/
    @PostMapping("/register")
    fun register(@ModelAttribute("student")student: Student, model: Model):String{
        println("Details of the course Details ${student.course}")
        studentService.saveStudent(student)
        return "welcome"
    }
```

> when I hit localhost:8080 it shows me below type of error

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Dec 13 17:09:34 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Comment: I think you don't have any mapping for root path "/". The 404 error usually means the server can't find a response for the given path

Comment: Also, When Spring boot encounters an error it will look for a view mapped at /error. In your case, add an error.html template as well

Answer (score 0):

did you set thymeleaf prefix in application.properties ?
`spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:./templates/`

Answer (score 0):

The default value for Thymeleaf prefix is classpath:/templates/ and for suffix .html [source.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M2/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#:%7E:text=prefix%20and%20spring.-,thymeleaf.,bean%20of%20the%20same%20name.) That seems correct but you can check if you have overwritten these values in your yml/properties configuration. Also check if you have Thymeleaf added as a dependency in Gradle, reloading the Gradle project if necessary. Finally, check if you have the @Controller annotation on your controller class along with the appropriate @RequestMapping.